# Pandas logical arguments do not work (AND / OR)

Tags: python, pandas, logic

I build the following toy code to illustrate my problem. 
I have some weights and need to pick specific combinations. This can be either that one weight = 1 (as in mask 1), or that certain combinations of weights apply (mask2). However, mask 2 does does somehow not work (at least the second part). 
For illustration: Due to `mask1` only rows with weights of 1 in specific columns should remain. 
However, the output also gives me rows, such as row 1, that should not be there cause `sumABCD` is always 1 (see below).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# random dataframe:
np.random.seed(seed=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5000,size=(2000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
columns = list(df.columns)
for col in columns: # round up at certain threshold, to simulate weightings of 1
    other_columns = [x for x in columns if not x == col]
    df.loc[df[col] > 4700, col] = 5000
    df.loc[df[col] == 5000, other_columns] = 0

# calculate weights:
df[list(df.columns)] = df.div(df[["A", "B", "C", "D"]].sum(axis=1), axis="index")
df["sumABCD"] = df[["A", "B", "C", "D"]].sum(axis=1)

# filter
mask1 = ((df[["A", "B", "C", "D"]] == 1).any(axis=1))
for x in [0, 0.10]:
    mask2 = ((df["B"] <= x) & (df["sumABCD"] < 1.0))
    test = df[mask1 | mask2]
    print(test.head(20))

           A         B         C         D  sumABCD
1   0.287745  0.014313  0.419938  0.278004      1.0
3   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000      1.0
8   0.000000  0.000000  1.000000  0.000000      1.0
12  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000      1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:

As for you updated question on  `row 1` issue, try run below command on your data

```
df.loc[df["sumABCD"] < 1.0, "sumABCD"].map('{0:.30f}'.format)

Out[28]:
1       0.999999999999999888977697537484
13      0.999999999999999888977697537484
44      0.999999999999999888977697537484
53      0.999999999999999888977697537484
57      0.999999999999999888977697537484
```

It slices on `sumABCD` columns < 1.0. Row 1 is not actually `1.0`. Its values is almost `1.0` and got rounded up to `1.0`. Because of its representation of numbers in the computer system, `float` is not guaranteed keeping the precision in arithmetic operations. `sumABCD` is the sum of divisions on each column. Those divisions caused loss in precision, so the sum only getting back to `almost 1.0`

*If you want more info on `float`, read this docs* https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

---

IIUC, in your sample code, you think you should get empty dataframe, but it doesn't.

After this

```
mask2 = ((df["B"] <= x) & (df["sumABCD"] < 1.0))
```

`mask2` is always `False` due to  `(df["sumABCD"] < 1.0)` is always `False`

However, you slicing `df` on `|` operator as in

```
test = df[mask1 | mask2]
```

So, `mask2` all `False` won't affect the result. When `mask2` is all `False`, the result is depended on `mask1`. That is the nature of `'|'` operator. Therefore `test` will depend on `True/False` of `mask1`. That is the reason `test` is not empty dataframe as you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the question a bit. It is more that mask2 should indeed be false, but I still get rows where mask1 and mask2 are False (see above).

Comment: @user27074: `df["sumABCD"]` of `row 1`is not `1.0` due to the loss of precision on float after divsion. I edited the answer adding more explanation. Please check the edited.